# Use ActionBar compability version with Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I followed the code in the [ActionBar compability version](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html)

When I use the code for API level 10 or less than it, it shows a ActionBar, but when I use it for API level 11 or greater, It does not show logo icon and Action items.

I checked the classes and I understood:

ActionBarHelperBase : API level 10 or less.

ActionBarHelperHoneycomb : API level 11 or greater.

ActionBarHelperICS : API level 14 or greater.

What is the best way to fix the ActionBar for Android Version 3.0 or greater? Specially Android 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the Manifest file. I should remove `android:theme="@style/Theme.ThemeCompabilityVersion`    from the Manifest file.

Then I need to check the version in the code in OnCreate() method like:

```
private void setTheme() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
        setTheme(R.style.ThemeCompabilityVersion);
    else 
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);         
}
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Comment: Yes but I was not able to do it for some hours. Now I am able and I fixed it.

Comment: What is this `R.style`, is it able to compile both for and without action bar?

Comment: Yes. @NoBugs Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html. for  complete information.

Answer (score 1):

There is an incredible project called [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) that allows to use all the ActionBar functionality in API over 2.X

It will took you a sample project to understand and set the dependencies and it will solve a lot of your problems :) just call getSupportActionBar() and all methods will be available.

Some common errors that i made was to not setting the Theme correctly.

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

<item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
```

Then you have to apply that Theme to each activity that will have ActionBar support or to the application tag.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:name=".ApplicationClass"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled">
```

Also you can set a menu.xml containing the items on the Bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:title="TestMe"
      android:menuCategory="system"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_launch"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:title="Test2"
      android:menuCategory="secondary"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/menu_go"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:title="Test"
      android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

The most interesting thing that i learned is that each activity or fragment can put their actions on the bar, so if a fragment is searchable an option with magnifying glass icon can be set, etc.

It had some problems with fragments in a prior version, in current version seems to be solved, i can put some example code to set it up with [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) and fragment support if needed.

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Comment: I appreciate, yes I knew about ActionBarSherlock, but do you how to solve my prblem in the mentined example by google?

Comment: hello! I want to use RoboGuice with Action Bar (new Android support v7 library is preferred), but I don't know how to deal with `RoboActivity` and `ActionBarActivity` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

ActionbarSherlock is higly recommended, a much more complete and advanced compability version.  It uses the native actionbar if running on an android version having one etc of course.

[actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but I am looking for a solution of the problem that I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your `targetSdkVersion` to `11` or higher? You can keep a lower `minSdkVersion`, for example:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wrote in the Manifest file.

Comment: And you are following the required order of method calls in "onCreateOptionsMenu" ?

Comment: yes I copied and pasted the example in the link. as I said :http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Comment: I think the problem is here: android:theme="@style/AppTheme">    (in the manifest file)

Comment: Well do you have the resource styles.xml from that example project?

Comment: Yes I solved the problem.  The problem was in the Manifest file. I just need to check the version in the code and then use the Theme for API level 10 or less.